# 12031 winapi error: httpsendrequest

Tags: winapi, c++, wininet

Есть клиент и есть сервер, оба на С++, клиент под WinCE, сервер под WinServer. 
Вы, наверное, удивитесь, но для обмена по сети с клиента используются функции WinInet, в частности HttpSendRequest, а для обработки на сервере - accept и recv.

Код клиента:

```
hConnect = InternetConnect(hHttpOpen, server, port, NULL, NULL,INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0,0);
hHttpRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, NULL, _T("/"), NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 0);
HttpAddRequestHeaders(hHttpRequest, lpHeader,  wcslen(lpHeader), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE | HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
HttpSendRequest(hHttpRequest, lpHeader, wcslen(lpHeader), (LPVOID)szAnsi, strlen(szAnsi));
```

Код сервера:

```
client_socket = accept(mysocket, (sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addr_size));
// ...
#define BUFFER_SIZE 8000000
my_sock = ((SOCKET *)client_socket)[0];
bytes_recv = recv(my_sock, &buff[0], BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
```

При длине szAnsi порядка 996 получил 12031 ошибку (INTERNET_CONNECTION_RESET) на клиенте, в HttpSendRequest. При этом все обычно проходило нормально, код работал и на бОльших объемах, но тут внезапно перестало работать. Предполагал, что на сервере буфера не хватает, и с этим связана ошибка, но буфера хватает. Настройки linker->system в студии (стек и память) выставлены на значения заведомо больше, чем буффер.

Ну и для полноты картины - клиент на WinCE соединяется через Wi-Fi. Сеть локальная, никаких брэндмауэров, файерволлов.

Comment: Очень похоже на то, что дело в MTU :( Хотя могу и заблуждаться.

Answer (score 2):

Правильный ответ: к черту WinInet. Переделал клиента на сокеты и обмен по 512 байт по сети.

С помощью WinInet невозможно сделать обмен chunk'ами: HttpSendRequest ждет закрытия сокета на стороне сервера! (злой смайл). Если сокет закрывать, то на сервере открывается новый поток при новом подключении.